# stored procedure case statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am building this where condition by concatenating the @whereClause variable in my stored procedure. At this point I am using the case to add additional values. if there a better way to do this?

```
SET @whereClause  = 
    ( CASE  
        -- APPType Clinical
         WHEN (@ApplicationType = 'Clinical') THEN @whereClause + ' AND vpgl.AppType = Clinical'
         -- APPType Patients
         WHEN (@ApplicationType = 'Patients') THEN @whereClause + ' AND vpgl.AppType = Patients'
          -- APPType Web
         WHEN (@ApplicationType = 'Web') THEN @whereClause + ' AND vpgl.AppType = null'
         ELSE @whereClause
       END  
    )
```

Comment: Shouldn't `= Clinical` be `= 'Clinical'`? Shouldn't `= null` be `IS NULL`? Why not just pass that in as a proper parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a better, safer, more self-documenting, and more scalable approach:

```
IF @ApplicationType IN ('Clinical','Patients')
BEGIN
  SET @whereClause += N' AND vpgl.AppType = @ApplicationType';
END

IF @ApplicationType = 'Web'
BEGIN
  SET @whereClause += N' AND vpgl.AppType IS NULL';
END

...
SET @sql = @sql + @whereClause;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql,
     N'@ApplicationType varchar(32)',
     @ApplicationType;
```

If you really, really want to use a `CASE` expression (which is [not meant for control of flow](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression)), you can say:

```
SET @whereClause += CASE 

   WHEN @ApplicationType IN ('Clinical','Patients')
   THEN N' AND vpgl.AppType = @ApplicationType'

   WHEN @ApplicationType = 'Web'
   THEN N' AND vpgl.AppType IS NULL';

   ELSE N'' END;

...
SET @sql = @sql + @whereClause;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql,
     N'@ApplicationType varchar(32)',
     @ApplicationType;
```

Comment: would I need to do something like this `SET @whereClause += N' AND vpgl.AppType =' + @ApplicationType + ';`

Comment: @Jefferson No, because you should be passing that in as a parameter. String concatenation is messy (you need to add doubled-up single quotes) and dangerous (it helps enable SQL injection).

Comment: right like this `@ApplicationType as varchar(50) = NULL` but will it just take the string value so it would look this`vpgl.AppType = @ApplicationType`

Comment: @Jefferson did you try it? Maybe to clarify I'll show that the variable that holds `@ApplicationType` is _different_ from the param you pass it into for the dynamic SQL. `DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @AppVariable varchar(32) = 'from variable'; 

SET @sql = N'SELECT app_from_param_but_really_from_variable = @AppParam;'; 

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@AppParam varchar(32)', @AppParam = @AppVariable;` or see [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b2d33ed03831b813e61423ead20fdd4).

Comment: I understand what you mean now Thanks You

Answer (score 0):

You can make it shorter:

```
SET @whereClause += (CASE @ApplicationType
                          -- APPType Clinical
                          WHEN 'Clinical' THEN ' AND vpgl.AppType = Clinical'
                          -- APPType Patients
                          WHEN 'Patients' THEN ' AND vpgl.AppType = Patients'
                          -- APPType Web
                          WHEN 'Web' THEN ' AND vpgl.AppType = null'
                          ELSE ''
                    END);
```